# Change color of icon status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a new user of Visual Studio Code, when I was using Atom there was something interesting, which was that when there were errors or warnings detected by my linter, the icons of the status bar changed color, however I realized that this does not occur in VS and would like to know if it's possible to do something about it. For me it is a small function that would help a lot in detecting errors in my code.

I'm using Typescript, more specify I'm using TSLint

[What I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXm5n.png)

Comment: Are you looking for any specific language error highlighting?

Comment: I'm using Typescript, more specify I'm using TSLint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but there are several changes you can make to the VScode status bar. The status bar is located at bottom of VScode window. The chages are listed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference